# Why pandas module is not being available while using ms-python extension in VS Code

Tags: python, vscode-extensions

I am new to VS Code for python. Earlier I was using spyder and it was working great. However, when I moved the below code base from spyder to VS Code and installed ms-python as extension, it did not work.

Below is the code snippet for py file named `test.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import os
file_path = 'C:\file_path\'
file_name = 'test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(file_path,file_name))
```

But I am getting error :

```
[ModuleNotFoundError]:Module pandas not found
```

However the above code works fine when I am using spyder.
My local machine `python --version` is 3.8. As per [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python&ssr=false#overview), `ms-python` should support the local machine version.

The moment I switch to anaconda python interpreter in VS code, things are working fine.

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Python extension looks for and uses the first Python interpreter it finds in the system path. It might be that you have multiple Python versions installed.

You can either create a new environment with `python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`  (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) and then [select Interpreter command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) and clicking on the Enter interpreter path or [manually specify Python path](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter).

Comment: I do have 2 python interpreter installed in my system. And I want to stick to use only the one that came with anaconda i.e. python 3.8. Just a quick side question: If I want to use the above script in Azure function and with python 3.8 interpreter, would it cause problem?

Comment: I don't know about Azure. As a rule of thumb, Python environments are important, better spend some time with them at the beginning of your project. And decide whether you want to use conda or pip and stick to one to avoid conflicts between the two package managers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows:
in your vs codes terminal type

> pip install pandas

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).